What is the meaning of "you have a demon" and why did the audience claim that Jesus had one?


John 7:20 - The people answered and said, “You have a demon. Who    is seeking to kill You?”


This seems rather odd given the context.

What is the meaning of "you have a demon"? Is it an idiom?
What caused the crowd to think that Jesus was under demonic influence?
Was it culturally normal to accuse people of having a demon?

Firstly, addressing to the questions;

The phrase "you have a demon" is likely an idiom in this context.
The adverse response from the crowd (primarily the Jewish leaders and their supporters) was a reaction to their malicious plan being exposed by Jesus. In John 7:19, Jesus said, "Why are you trying to kill me?"
It might have been a culturally normal to accuse people of having a demon. As Jesus warned His disciples in Matthew 5:22: "But I tell you that anyone who is angry with a brother or sister will be subject to judgment. Again, anyone who says to a brother or sister, ‘Raca,’ is answerable to the court. And anyone who says, ‘You fool!’ will be in danger of the fire of hell." (NIV)

Let's delve into the context in John 7:11-20 NIV;

11 Now at the festival the Jewish leaders were watching for Jesus and asking, “Where is he?” 12 Among the crowds there was widespread whispering about him. Some said, “He is a good man.” Others replied, “No, he deceives the people.” 13 But no one would say anything publicly about him for fear of the leaders. 14 Not until halfway through the festival did Jesus go up to the temple courts and begin to teach. 15 The Jews there were amazed and asked, “How did this man get such learning without having been taught?” 16 Jesus answered, “My teaching is not my own. It comes from the one who sent me. 17 Anyone who chooses to do the will of God will find out whether my teaching comes from God or whether I speak on my own. 18 Whoever speaks on their own does so to gain personal glory, but he who seeks the glory of the one who sent him is a man of truth; there is nothing false about him. 19 Has not Moses given you the law? Yet not one of you keeps the law. Why are you trying to kill me?”
20 “You are demon-possessed,” the crowd answered. “Who is trying to kill you?”

Clearly, the crowd can be divided into two groups: those in favor of Jesus and those against Him. The latter group consisted of the Jewish leaders and their supporters. They attempted to undermine Jesus' teachings by questioning His authority (John 7:12) and His background (John 7:15).
For the Jewish leaders, one's background was indicative of their education and authority. Paul, for instance, declared in Acts 22:3 that he studied under Gamaliel, who is described in Acts 5:34, as "a Pharisee, teacher of the law, who was honored by all the people".
When the Jewish leaders' malicious intentions were exposed to the public, they became furious and accused Jesus of being demon-possessed. This accusation was likely an idiom at the time, equivalent to calling someone a public menace. Since this idiom was spoken by the Jewish leaders, it might have been widely accepted by the public. Consequently, Jesus had to warn His disciples in Matthew 5:22.

Yes, it was an idiom, and a language use of that culture.  We would say "Are you insane, who is trying to kill you?"  It was of pagan cultism outside of Jerusalem, in and around Galilee where most of the "casting out" language was used which is an Aramaic idiom for making one sane.
Notice the state of the "demonaic" after Jesus "cast out" the legion demons in Luke 8:35 -

and they came forth to see what was come to pass, and they came unto Jesus, and found the man sitting, out of whom the demons had gone forth, clothed, and right-minded, at the feet of Jesus, and they were afraid; (YLT)

The belief in demons was of pagan origin, and they used that phrase for anyone who was acting out of the norm, or had a disease they could not explain.  See Duncan Heaster's work on the real devil here.  God always used the language of their culture so the people would understand that His power exceeded any so-called demon power.
Paul made it clear that "demons" were no-gods, idols, nothing.

18 See Israel according to the flesh! are not those eating the sacrifices in the fellowship of the altar? 19 what then do I say? that an idol is anything? or that a sacrifice offered to an idol is anything? --


20 [no,] but that the things that the nations sacrifice -- they sacrifice to demons and not to God; and I do not wish you to come into the fellowship of the demons.

Demons were the same as idols, no-gods, nothing.  The word translated in the Hebrew scriptures as "demon" is Stong's H8163, "sayir" which means a hairy goat.  It was only used 4 times in the old testament and it was defined as an idol, a no-god.

They sacrifice to demons -- no god! Gods they have not known -- New ones -- from the vicinity they came; Not feared them have your fathers!  (Deu. 32:17, YLT)


They have made Me **zealous by no-god**,' They made Me angry by their vanities; And I make them zealous by no-people,' By a foolish nation I make them angry. (Deu. 32:21, YLT)


36 And they served their idols: which were a snare unto them. 37 Yea, they sacrificed their sons and their daughters unto devils, 38 And shed innocent blood, even the blood of their sons and of their daughters, whom they sacrificed unto the idols of Canaan: and the land was polluted with blood. (Psa. 106:36-38, KJV)

Whereas in the YLT Psa. 106:36-38 is translated as:

36 And serve their idols, And they are to them for a snare. 37 And they sacrifice their sons And their daughters to destroyers, 38 And they shed innocent blood -- Blood of their sons and of their daughters, Whom they have sacrificed to idols of Canaan, And the land is profaned with blood.

Excerpt from my post Testing The Spirits - Part VI(a): Demons, Devils, & Idols:
"Paul said that idols are nothing, they do not exist. As Paul also equated idols with demons, therefore demons are also nothing and do not exist. They are the false ideas, the false creations of man’s imaginations. And, where does the Bible say that evil comes from ? – the heart of man (Gen. 6:5; 8:21; Psa. 14:1-3; Prov. 19:3; Jer. 7:24; Ezek 14:3-4; Matt. 12:35; Matt. 15:18; Mark 7:20-23)."
See also the posts at my blog for :
Testing The Spirits - Part VI(b): Demons, Devils, & Idols
Testing The Spirits - Part VI(c): Demons, Devils, & Idols
